# Google recaptcha admin panel not showing domains which are added

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, recaptcha

We have account where we added google recaptcha key, and added domains to it, now when i open that account in admin panel for that account, the domain list is empty it is not showing old domains which we have added to this account

Now I am not able to add the domains to the existing account.

Any information regarding this issue.

Thanks

Comment: I can confirm that this is definitely a global issue that started happening within the last 24 hours or so, there are several threads in the recaptcha Google Group about it too. No word if Google is actively working on a fix yet or not though that I could see.

Comment: Thanks, they have fixed it, it is working now